# I have two columns with started_at and ended_at. I want to subtract two columns to find the difference in only time as hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

subtracting two columns and result in hh:mm:ss format

I tried working on finding out the difference between two columns but it is showing in negative minutes. I want to get answer as hh:mm:ss format.
below is the code I used to subtract the time.

```
SELECT 
started_at, ended_at,
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(started_at, ended_at, MINUTE) as diff
 FROM 
 avid-winter-405805.bikesharingdata.jan
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) of `timestamp_diff`, the later timestamp must be written before the earlier one to obtain a positive value.

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) as diff
```